# Bidirectional vs. Traditional LSTM

Tags: lstm, computer-vision, pytorch

I'm working on image captioning problem, where I need to have an encoder for image and decoder for caption generation. Regarding the decoder, I've found a reference that uses Pytorch LSTM where `bidirectional` parameter is `False`. However, I know that bidirectional LSTM is more accurate. So, what do you think about this comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bidrectional LSTMs are still traditional and so I believe you refer to unidirectional LSTM models.

#### Concept

Unidirectional LSTM layers only preserve information of the past, as inputs are processed at each time point in a sequential forward pass. This means that, at each time-point the sequence model only reads information from the past. However bidirectional LSTM layers, are able to process inputs from the future in a backward pass, additional the the forward. In this way, the sequence model is able to preserve and "memorise" information from the past but also from the future.

#### Hidden state

The hidden state of a bidirectional LSTM layer is double in size (forward and backward pass) to enable allows at any point in time the alleged preservation of information the past and future.

### In short

In essence, bidirectional LSTM models generally show better results as they can understand context better.